# infinite loop of alert messages

Tags: javascript

I want to display alert message and then refresh the page.

But it take infinite loop of alert messages.

```
   if(isValid){
      alert("alert some text");
      document.location.reload(true);
   }
   else {
       .............
   }
```

How can I do that with out infinite loop

Comment: Find the condition that causes `isValid` to be true and prevent it?

Comment: By the looks of your code, you're trying to alert the user, and then refresh the page, but the condition still evaluates to true after it's been refreshed. What are you actually trying to achieve here? Are you sure you're not just messing up the condition?

Comment: Do you want to run this code until the password and username are correct?

Comment: Are you asking how you can alert only once?

Comment: the code is correct, I think you're setting the `isValid` variable somewhere before the if block incorrectly. Also I think the if condition should be `!isValid`

Comment: @Ates Goral Yes. I want to alert only once.

Comment: There are a few ways you do this (alert once), but it would be more productive for all of us if you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve. What is this alert for? And why do you need to reload? Do you need to reload the exact same URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass along the state. Possibly refreshing the page by pointing itself with a querystring variable. Then read that variable

```
if (getParameterByName("reloaded") != "yes") {
    alert("username or password are incorrect");       
    window.location = 'mypage.html?reloaded=yes';  
} else {
    // Do something else..
}
```

Note the `getParameterByName` function is found at another stackoverflow answer: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript). You could alternatively use a library such as jQuery for a better solution.